# ASP.NET: Creating an interface for a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interfaces, class

Would creating a controller's `interface` a bad idea? I have a controller that derived from `ApiController`, so knowing that you can only derived one class to a class but able to derived one or more interface to a class.

```
public class FooController : ApiController
```

My problem is I have code that is in another controller that can be used in `FooController`. I don't want to repeat the code so I'm thinking to create a base class that will hold common codes and create an interface for the base class. Would this be considered a bad idea or any suggestion on this?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to create an interface, if you propose to create a common base controller.

Comment: @Gaste because the controller that will be using the common codes in base controller is already derived in `ApiController`

Comment: I thought you want something like `class BaseController : ApiController`, which implements the common methods. Then inherit the two controllers using the common code from `BaseController`: `class FooController : BaseController` and `class BarController : BaseController`

Comment: @Gaste and if the controller is not derived in `ApiController` only in `Controller`? my problem is I have two controllers that use common codes. First controller is derived in `Controller`; Second controller is derived in `ApiController`. If I'll be making `BaseController` derived from `ApiController` then I would be having problem using it with the controller that does not derived from `ApiController` but `Controller`

Comment: A interface only specifies the *signatures* of the methods, *not* the implementation. So if you specify the commonly used methods in an `interface ICommonController`, you still have to implement the interface in all controllers: `class FooController : ApiController, ICommonController` and `class BarController : Controller, ICommonController`. Depending on what the commonly used code does, you could however move it into another class (and possibly abstract the behaviour using an interface), which is then injected as dependency in the controllers.

Comment: Pull the common code out into a third class, and any controller will be able to use it.